# Trying to determine Device Type using CSS and Jquery not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to detect the clients device dimensions using a mixture between CSS and Javascript. [[From this tutorial]](https://davidwalsh.name/device-state-detection-css-media-queries-javascript) I created an element that I appended to the body and assigned it a class that holds a value called "z-index" that determines the device type. However when running the following code I get "undefined" as the response.

How can I get a numeric value instead of undefined?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var indicator = document.createElement('div');
  indicator.className = 'state-indicator';
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(indicator);

  function getDeviceState() {
    var index = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(indicator).getPropertyValue('z-index'), 10);

    var states = {
      0: 'desktop',
      1: 'small-desktop',
      2: 'large-tablet',
      3: 'medium-tablet',
      4: 'phone'
    };

    return states[index];
  }

  console.log(getDeviceState());

});
```

```css
/*default */

.state-indicator {
  z-index: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
  /* start of small desktop */
  .state-indicator {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
/* end of desktop styles */

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  /* start of large tablet styles */
  .state-indicator {
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* start of medium tablet styles */
  .state-indicator {
    z-index: 3;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  /* start of phone styles */
  .state-indicator {
    z-index: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements, if you check what the actual value is it is `auto` and `states[parseInt('auto')]` is undefined

Css adjustment that fixes immediate issue:

```
.state-indicator {
  z-index: 0;
  position:relative;
}
```

Since you are using jQuery here's a slightly simpler version that also removes the element once the needed value is obtained

```
$(function() {      

    function getDeviceState() {        
        var $indicator = $('<div>', {'class': 'state-indicator'});
        $('body').append($indicator);

        var index = $indicator.css('z-index');
        // got the value, so remove the test element
        $indicator.remove();
        // technically js property names can not be numeric, and will get cast to string but not all browsers will
        var states = {
          '0': 'desktop',
          '1': 'small-desktop',
          '2': 'large-tablet',
          '3': 'medium-tablet',
          '4': 'phone'
        };

        return states[index];
      }

      console.log(getDeviceState());
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ahgnqxgo/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `z-index`which is `auto` can not be parsed to a number. The resolution of this code is to find `NaN` property of `states` object and the right answer is `undefined`.

So, right question is `why does window.getComputedStyle(indicator).getPropertyValue('z-index') returns auto and how to make it works`.

The main problem is to find right media-query resolution from whithin JS.

There is a lot of good example how to combine JS and media query work. Try this one:

http://theme.co/blog/cubit-a-more-flexible-media-query/

http://thenewcode.com/948/Triggering-JavaScript-Actions-With-CSS-Media-Queries

You can improve this code with ideas inside links I gave you.

Comment: while those links might be of interest, link only answers are not considered to be of value here. Links rot and answers should be self contained. Links should only be used as a reference to support what actually exists in the answer

Comment: You are right. My answer is about "right way of media query resolution problem solving within js", because the code example is wrong one as I can see. The links and example is some kind of 'hack' and there is working vs. not-working example of such hacki-way I gave. Is solution with jQuery  better then offer to use matchMedia? I don't think so. The "problem of media query resolution from within js" is the answer. Why does `undefined` returns I have explained also. If you can improve my answer - I will be grateful.

Comment: do a writeup on matchQuery then , and use links as reference. I made my answer fix the OP question code.... let op decide what is best but agree that matchQuery is much simpler